# Different output of lsof variant

Tags: lsof, minecraft

I have a Java application utilizing the MongoDB Java driver (2.11.3). I'm using one static MongoClient instance across the whole application and as stated in the docs it should handle the connection pooling. After a long time (It's a BungeeCord, if you're familiar with Minecraft) it throws Too many open files exceptions. Having a look at

```
$ lsof -p 7616 -n | grep "123.456.7.8:27017" | wc -l
6
```

shows us that there are 16 connections to port 27017. But when we look at:

```
$ lsof -n | grep "123.456.7.8:27017" | awk '{print $2}' | grep 7616 | wc -l
438
```

it shows us a lot more connections than the first command.

First question is why do the 2 commands have different output and the second is whether anyone of you has experienced something similar with the Java MongoDB driver.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and explain why you would expect to see the same result? You're grepping for `16062` in the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's clearer. However, without seeing the output of the two commands, we can't tell you what's going on. For example, could you have a PID like `17616`? Please include the output of the commands so we can understand. Also, this site is more like a wiki than a forum. Don't add sequential edits, just edit the question itself (I have now done so).

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure without seeing your actual output but the likeliest explanation is that `27017` appears in different places. Your first command will list files for the process with PID `5253`, then prints all lines that contain `27017` *anywhere in the line*.

Your second command will print all open files and then, again, you are selecting all lines that  contain `27017` *anywhere in the line*. I assume you are actually grepping for `27017` in the second command as well and not for `16062` as you show in your question.

In any case, neither of your commands is looking specifically at port `27017`. In fact, I don't even see why you expect that a port will be listed. `lsof` looks at files, not ports. No ports are shown when I look for `ssh` in the output of `lsof -n` on my system for example.

Anyway, to give you a more concrete example:

```
$ sudo lsof -np 7033 | head
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
firefox 7033 terdon  cwd    DIR                8,6   491520  16646145 /home/terdon
firefox 7033 terdon  rtd    DIR                8,7   548864         2 /
firefox 7033 terdon  txt    REG                8,7   143680   1841618 /opt/firefox/firefox
firefox 7033 terdon  DEL    REG               0,30           10335506 /tmp/.glT5RaDf
firefox 7033 terdon  mem    REG                8,7 12303504   1573445 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont.ttf
firefox 7033 terdon  DEL    REG                0,4          970489906 /SYSV00000000
firefox 7033 terdon  mem    REG                8,7  7470672    540090 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so
firefox 7033 terdon  mem    REG                8,7  5177387   1580807 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc
firefox 7033 terdon  mem    REG                8,7   120688    532953 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoscale.so
```

Your search for `27017` could match in any of the fields. It could be the size, or the PID or the node or whatever. It could also be part of another number. For example:

```
$ printf "12345\n12" | grep 12
12345
12
```

As you can see above, `12` is matched on both lines, not only on the second where it forms a word. You can use the `-w` switch to make `grep` match against whole words only:

```
$ printf "12345\n12" | grep -w 12
12
```

So, since you are not restricting the output by PID in the second command, your two `grep`s could be matching anywhere at all on each line so, of course, you have different output.